# Getting different bitmap object from same image file

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, bitmapimage

I am creating Bitmap object from the same image, but in the end getting different results. It should calculate deviation from the image colors and images are the same so why results are different?

```
 double test1 = GetStdDev("C:\\temp\\images\\file.jpg");
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap("C:\\temp\\images\\file.jpg");
 double test2 = GetStdDev(img);

 public static double GetStdDev(string imageFileName)
 {
        double total = 0, totalVariance = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double stdDev = 0;

        // First get all the bytes
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imageFileName))
        {
            BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                int nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
                for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; ++y)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; ++x)
                    {
                        count++;

                        byte blue = p[0];
                        byte green = p[1];
                        byte red = p[2];

                        int pixelValue = Color.FromArgb(0, red, green, blue).ToArgb();
                        total += pixelValue;
                        double avg = total / count;
                        totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - avg, 2);
                        stdDev = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);

                        p += 3;
                    }
                    p += nOffset;
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bmData);
        }

        return stdDev;
  }

 private static double GetStdDev(Bitmap img)
 {
        double total = 0, totalVariance = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double stdDev = 0;

        // First get all the bytes
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img))
        {
            BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                int nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
                for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; ++y)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; ++x)
                    {
                        count++;

                        byte blue = p[0];
                        byte green = p[1];
                        byte red = p[2];

                        int pixelValue = Color.FromArgb(0, red, green, blue).ToArgb();
                        total += pixelValue;
                        double avg = total / count;
                        totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - avg, 2);
                        stdDev = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);

                        p += 3;
                    }
                    p += nOffset;
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bmData);
        }

        return stdDev;
    }
```

Comment: **1)** Why does `GetStdDev(Bitmap img)` create a new image instead of iterating the one it's given? **2)** Why not just have `GetStdDev(string imageFileName)` load the image and call `GetStdDev(Bitmap img)`?

Comment: The problem is that when i call GetStdDev(Bitmap img) it gets wrong result and can't understand why...

Comment: I don't know why there's a difference but I don't understand how either of the methods produces any meaningful result. Are you sure you understand what `Color.ToArgb()` returns?

Comment: i'm trying to use this functionality http://www.chinhdo.com/20080910/detect-blank-images/ but in my case i need to use bitmap instead image file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found solution, it was problem with deep copying bitmap object. instead using new Bitmap(img) use Bitmap img2 = (Bitmap) img.Clone(); don't know it is the right solution, but it does the job.